# Making an equal amount of positive and negative energy?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, cosmology, energy-conservation

I was wondering if it would be possible to create an amount of positive energy  out of a vacuum, in addition to an equal amount of negative energy, thus not violating the first law of thermodynamics, since the total amount of energy in the universe would remain the same. It could be like an "energy loan," with the positive energy being like the "loan money," and the negative energy being like the "debt."  Is this theoretically (or even practically) possible?

For example, I am asking if you could create 200 units of positive energy out of a vacuum, as long as you also created 200 units of negative energy too, so as not to violate the second law of thermodynamics. By negative energy, I mean energy that is below 0 degrees Kelvin.

I came across the idea as I was reading about the zero-energy universe theory. It suggested that this mechanism was what made the universe, and that it could have been started by an unusually large quantum fluctuation.

Does this idea conflict with the second law of thermodynamics in any way? Would entropy have to be considered, since negative energy reduces entropy, violating the second law? If so, is there a way of changing the idea a bit so there as to avoid the problem? Could "quantum interest" account for the missing entropy?

Do any restrictions apply on the negative and positive energy, such as quantum inequalities? Can the positive and negative energy be separated? Is there a way to get around the restrictions, if there are any?

Finally, if all of this is possible, could it be done? Would a possible method be to recreate an unusually large quantum fluctuation, as described in the second paragraph? Are there other ways of making the "energy loan"?

Comment: If by creating negative energy you mean taking away energy from a system, then your analogy reduces to a net transfer of energy, which happens everyday. And it also follows the second law of thermodynamics. If this is not what you were thinking, could you more clearly describe how you would want "negative energy" to look like? PS "energy loans" and "debts" are not good examples.

Comment: Doesn't this happen all the time already?  If I recall, the amount of time that this "loan" can be outstanding is inversely proportional to its size. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_fluctuation

Comment: @Michael A quantum fluctuation is not what I am talking about. A fluctuation is a tiny burst of energy that happens because of the uncertainty principle, and then quickly disappears, because it violates the first law of thermodynamics. What I am suggesting is a larger amount of energy that is accompanied by an equal amount of negative energy. The positive energy shouldn't have to disappear, because it does not violate the first law of thermodynamics when balanced by an equal amount of negative energy.

Comment: "negative energy, I
mean energy that is below 0 degrees
Kelvin." This doesn't make sense energy doesn't temperature, objects do. And negative temperature is well know.